# Android Datepicker Single Cell Color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, datepicker

Hi I'd like to be able to choose a few dates in the month and change the color of it. Say in my application I want the dates 3, 4, 8  of September to be red so that the user would be able to know that at those specific dates there is already a submission. Is this possible, if so how? Thanks in advance!

edit. Ive tried searching the forums, searching other places, and have not been able to get an answer.

To make things clear, Im not just looking to change the color theme, Im looking to change the color of *specific* dates. Say the user has submitted something for the 8th of September. I want my application date picker to show that by changing the color of the number 8 in the datepicker window.

Answer (score 1):

check the [library](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) to show date with the different colour themes:

Add to your styles.xml

```
<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/beautiful_color</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/beautiful_color</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">calendar</item>
</style>
```

Moreover, if you want to change the entire theme of the date picker, use the following dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.6.3'
}
```

You can use app:mcv_dateTextAppearance (or the Java setter) to do this. I don't have the full explanation, but for now, you can copy the default implementation and modify as you need. Essentially you need to supply a android:textColor that is a color state list with your desired colors.

Add a style:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.MyCustomDay" parent="android:TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_custom_day_color</item>
</style>
```

and create color/my_custom_day_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:enterFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="SELECTION_COLOR" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="SELECTION_COLOR" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false"  android:color="#808080" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/black" />
</selector>
```

then set app:mcv_dateTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MyCustomDay"

Comment: Hi @Paramjeet ...Next time whenever u give the answer, add some code in it.**References Only answers** here in **SO** not _allowed_ because the link can be expired or finished in the future, so please in next time give some description along with **link**.. Enjoy coding and keep helping others :)

Comment: As Ive written in my question, this is for android studio... Not html... I have no idea with the link you gave me

Comment: please check updated code references @RavindraKushwaha